# How can I return a promise from a function that calls a $http.get in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following function:

```
   getX: function ($scope) {
       $http.get('/api/X/GetSelect')
           .success(function (data) {
               ...
               ...
           })
           .error(function (data) {
               ...
           });
   },
```

I want this to always do the things in the .success block but I would like it to also return 
a promise so that I can call it like this:

```
getX($scope)
   .then( function () {
       doNextThing();
}
```

Can someone help by telling me how I can code it so a promise is returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy, you return a promise yourself. You need to inject `$q` for this ([take a look at the docs for more information](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)).

Then you can update your code to:

```
getX: function ($scope) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api/X/GetSelect').success(function (data) {
        ...
        ...
        defer.resolve();
    }).error(function (data) {
        ...
        defer.reject();
    });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It returns but it does not wait until the .success has run.

Comment: ? What do you mean by "does not wait until the success has run"? getX will return a promise, on which you can chain a `then` function like in your example code in your question.

Answer (score 5):

You just add the return statement before the $http.get() method. This will return the promise.

Example:

```
 return $http.get('/api/X/GetSelect')
       .success(function (data) {
           ...
           ...
       })
       .error(function (data) {
           ...
       });
```

Comment: +1. This is actually a better answer. Forgot it returns a promise :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function getX($scope)
{
    var defered = $q.defer();
     $http.get('/api/X/GetSelect')
               .success(function (data) {
                   defered.resolve(data);
                   ...
               })
               .error(function (data) {
                   defered.reject();
               });
    return defered.promise();
    }
```

You need to inject $q into your contorller.

Comment: I tried this. It returns but it does not wait until the .success has run.

Comment: you need to resolve the defered at the end of success code block.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use a deferred promise. This is how you could do it.

```
var functionA = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('url here').
          success(function (response) {
              deferred.resolve(response);
          }).
          error(function (response) {
          });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Now calling functionA should return you a promise on which you can perform manipulations as you needed.

Comment: I tried this. It returns but it does not wait until the .success has run.